# Peut-on mettre "il faudrait" au pluriel ?

Tags: conjugaison

Bonjour,

Je m'intérroge sur la phrase suivante :

> Vous avez des documents qu'il faudrait modifier immédiatement

Ce qu'il faudrait modifier ce sont les documents. Dois-je écrire :

- « qu'il faudrait » car c'est indéfini comme « il pleut »
- « qu'ils faudraient » pour montrer que ça se rapporte aux documents (qui sont au pluriel)
- les deux sont acceptables

Merci

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Falloir est un verbe défectif, comme pleuvoir. Il se conjugue à tous les temps mais seulement à la troisième personne du singulier.

Dans l'exemple, *les documents* est le complément d'objet du verbe *modifier*, pas le sujet du verbe *falloir*.

Answer (score 5):

**Non** - « falloir » est une verbe impersonnel, et donc se conjugue d'une façon spéciale, à savoir qu'à la troisième personne du singulier.

Sources:

1. [https://grammaire.reverso.net/falloir-valoir/#:~:text=Falloir%20%3A%20obligation,il%20fallait%20beaucoup%20de%20patience](https://grammaire.reverso.net/falloir-valoir/#:%7E:text=Falloir%20%3A%20obligation,il%20fallait%20beaucoup%20de%20patience).
2. https://www.the-conjugation.com/french/verb/falloir.php
3. https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/falloir